# Ajax jQuery MySql Delete field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a fields of phone numbers that are pulled from the database through ajax and what I'm trying to do is add a delete button next to the info Here is what I have so far it seems this should be working but it is not. I'm also using bootstrap.

HTML CODE:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo _e($_SESSION['id']); ?>" id="userid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>',_e($r->label),'</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>',_e($r->phone),'</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a class="delPhone" rel="',_e($r->id),'" href="#">
            Delete Number
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

AJAX CODE

```
$('.delPhone').on('click', function() {
    $id = $('#userid').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "functions.php",
        data: {"userid":$id, "phoneid": $(this).attr('rel')}, 
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });     
});
```

PHP CODE

```
if(isset($_POST['phoneid']) === true && isset($_POST['userid']) === true) {
    if(empty($_POST['phoneid']) === false && empty($_POST['userid']) === false) {
        $phoneid    = $_POST['phoneid'];
        $userid     = $_POST['userid'];
        require_once 'connect.php';
        $sql = "DELETE FROM numbers WHERE userid=:userid AND id=:phoneid";
        $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(
            ':userid'   => $userid,
            ':phoneid'  => $phoneid
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Comment out the `location.reload()` and see what message you get back from PHP? Also, your `error:`-function will never trigger, unless the PHP-file returns a HTTP-header error. You can also try to run a `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP-file, and check the data you get on the reutrn. Just put a `console.log(data);` instead of the `location.reload();`

Comment: Do you get any errors? What do you see in _inspector_ ?

Comment: What does "not working" mean here?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

The problem is that you are NOT specifying the value of $id in you AJAX which is why PHP doesn't know what to delete.

Error message:  **Uncaught ReferenceError: $id is not defined**

Comment: Sorry I didn't include in the fact that I did add a option for $id in the js file my bad I'll fix a few things and see if it works.

Comment: @theWebKeyGuy could you at least vote my answer up :)?